# How can I override a capacitive touch on-off switch?

Tags: sensor, electricity, capacitive, lamp

I bought a floor lamp for use with a mechanical timer that turns electricity on and off using a set schedule (for example, when you're away but want to convince others that you're still at home).

Unfortunately, this kind of lamp (I bought it at Target) won't work with a timer because when the timer removes power and then later restores it (normally, this turns a lamp on), the lamp stays off until someone touches it with a finger.

The sensor is on the side of the vertical column of the lamp and I can't mechanically access the sensor itself.

Can anyone think of a way to modify the lamp so as to ignore the sensor and light up when power is restored? Thanks!

Comment: very simple solution is to get a lamp with a mechanical switch

Comment: modifying the internal design is easy but that  requires you to reveal the design which is not (easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an electronic hobbyist, you could build a circuit that simulates a human finger:

You can get a big electrolytic capacitor (e.g. 2200uF 50V) which has the size of a human finger. Then you can move this capacitor on the switch with a servo motor, or you can try to electrically connect/disconnect one terminal to earth to trigger a capacitance change.